# How to determine if SharePoint server is hosted in cloud or on prem

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I'm using the SharePoint Online CSOM library to access different SharePoint servers. I want to be able to determine whether the server I am connecting to is SharePoint Online or an on-prem server.

I have seen some answers suggesting to check the web response header where the SharePoint version is returned, but I don't think that is a good solution since SharePoint 2016 on-prem is now released.

I've also seen a suggestion to check the `tenantAppVersion` in the `_spPageContextInfo` object, but I'm using C# and have not found a way to get access to anything like that.

Some have also suggested to check if ".sharepoint.com" is part of the domain name, but that doesn't work for custom domain names. So, how can this be done programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You could check the url in CSOM to determine if it is Online or On Premise:

```
ClientContext cc = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

if (siteUrl.Contains("sharepoint.com"))
{
    // this is for SPO, use SharePointOnlineCredentials class
    cc.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);
}
else
{
    // this is for On-Premise domain login 
    cc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for custom domain names where there is no ".sharepoint.com" in the name.

Comment: Why not? This is the correct answer. If it is SPO, it is cloud SharePoint and contains 'sharepoint.com' as part of the FQDN. Anything else is on-prem SharePoint, regardless if it is hosted in-house, in Azure/AWS/etc. or by a 3rd party company.

Comment: See my comment above. Custom SharePoint Online domain names do not contain ".sharepoint.com".

Comment: The only place you'll find custom SPO domains is with SPO-D. Are you working with SPO-D customers?

Comment: Not sure what plan they have, but I work with customers that have a custom domain for SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe below line of code after **ExeceuteQuery** can help you :

```
context.ServerVersion.Major.ToString()
```

OR

```
context.ServerVersion.ToString()
```

From the number returned above (example: 16.0.0.1203) the most important part is the first number.

12 = SharePoint 2007 (WSS or MOSS)

14 = SharePoint 2010

15 = SharePoint 2013

16 = SharePoint 2016, and generally SharePoint Online / Office 365

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. I need to know if the SharePoint server is hosted on-premise or in the cloud (Office 365). Using the ServerVersion might return 16 which could be either.

Comment: I cannot find any other solution. Maybe in that case you might want to check the range of build numbers(example: 16.0.0.1203) of on-premise and  the cloud (Office 365) returned by using ServerVersion .

Comment: I think any solution which uses build numbers is prone to breaking with future SharePoint releases. There needs to be a flag that indicates this is a cloud-hosted server. Does anyone know if such a flag already exists? If so, how can I access it via C#?

Comment: I don't think Microsoft has come up with anything to distinguish between On-Prem 2016 and cloud 2016 programmatically (in context of server version) apart from the fact that Cloud 2016 will have higher Minor build number than the On-Prem 2016 Minor build number. Can you check from your end as well, If this is true then this might help you. Thanks